# GnuPG signing manually in two steps?

Tags: gnupg

AFAIU signing in GnuPG is performed in two steps:

1. Create a digest of the file.
2. Encrypt the digest with the secret key.

Is there some way to actually split this into two steps on the command line?

The end-goal is to sign a file (detach-sign) with neither having to transfer it to the computer where the secret key is, nor transferring the secret key to where the file-to-be-signed is.

Answer (score -1):

> The end-goal is to sign a file (detach-sign) with neither having to
>   transfer it to the computer where the secret key is, nor transferring
>   the secret key to where the file-to-be-signed is.

What?
In order for a `gpg` process to create a signature, it needs both the input data to be signed and a private (secret) key to do the signing.

Your [logical] choices:

- Transfer the file to the `user@host` where the private key is, create detached-sig, delete file
- Use `ssh` or similar to pipe the file data from one host directly into `gpg` process on host where private key resides, avoiding need for input file to hit the disk on said host
- Use `openssl` or similar to create a digest hash / signature on the fly

Comment: No, those may be the options that GnuPG offers me. Internally GnuPG performs the two steps I listed in my question, which means that there is (logically) nothing that prevents a tool to offer the steps to be manually split.  The question is whether GnuPG offers a fourth option: 1) create hash of *large* file, 2) copy hash to other computer, 3) sign hash (i.e. create a detached signature of *large* file).

Comment: Magnus, you didn't ask about theory or logic; you asked if there was a way to make GnuPG do what you want  and I answered you, even providing alternatives. If you think that deserves a down-vote, then I gotta tell you: you're going to run out of karma down-voting all the other right answers on the various stackexchange sites.

Comment: I downvoted you because you clearly didn't read the question carefully enough to understand it before answering.